# heading off in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

PHP File:

```
<?php
require 'JSON.php'; // JSON.php
try
{
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "autoset") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $connection);
    mysql_select_db(test, $connection);
    $sql = "select * from Evaluation";
    $sth = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query error: " . mysql_error());
    // JSON 
    $json = new Services_JSON();
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth))
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $output = $json->encode($rows);
    echo $output;
    mysql_close($connection);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // Note: Log the error or something
}
?>
```

This is my JSON result:

```
[{"ENTERPRISE":"22","PERIOD":"53","EPS":"54","STOCKPRICE":"24","PER":"33"}]
```

How can I get fields without column names like this?

```
[22, 55, 54, 24, 33]
```

Comment: How are you getting that MySQL data?  (P.S. `[{"22","53","54","24","33"}]`  isn't valid JSON).

Comment: `[{"22","53","54","24","33"}]` isn't valid JSON (objects require keys).  `["22","53","54","24","33"]` would be (arrays don't have keys).

Comment: So you're not posting your actual code, and ask us how to change it?

Comment: What is `Services_JSON`?  Why not just use `json_encode`?

Comment: When building your array, don't just do `$rows[] = $r;`.  Loop through and just use the values (or use `array_values`).

Answer (score 2):

If you never want the MySQL data as an associative array keyed by column names, and always want a plain array with numeric indices, use **mysql_fetch_array($sth,MYSQL_NUM)** instead of **mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)** when extracting **$row** from the query resource. You should end up with an array of arrays in the resulting JSON, instead of an array of objects:

```
[[22, 55, 54, 24, 33]]
```

Comment: when I used mysql_fetch_array()
it shows
[{"0":"23","PER":"23"},{"0":"47","PER":"47"},{"0":"86","PER":"86"},{"0":"25","PER":"25"},{"0":"74","PER":"74"}] like this..


this is my php code I edited. still not working. 
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","autoset");
mysql_select_db("test");
 
$q=mysql_query("SELECT PER FROM Evaluation");
while($e=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        $output[]=$e;
 
print(json_encode($output)); 

mysql_close();

?>

Comment: I'd forgotten that mysql_fetch_array() requires MYSQL_NUM as the second parameter to ensure it returns **only** a numeric array. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: OK COOL~ I feel like I can fix this problem. but it still shows [["23"],["47"],["86"],["25"],["74"]] 
and my application isn't plotting T.T

you can see my edited question. it has more information
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708029/creating-jqplot-graph-using-php 
thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want an array of arrays, but rather one array with the values from the "PER" column (according to the other thread). So you're probably best off using mysql_fetch_assoc() and then appending only the value you want to the $rows array likely using $rows = $r["PER"].

Answer (score 1):

Decode it using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), then from there, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the dictionary.

Comment: Oh wait, that's an object in the middle. In this case, the `$assoc` parameter of `json_decode` needs to be true to parse it as an associative array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$values_data = array_values($data_from_sql);
$values_without_columns = json_encode($values_data );
?>
```