# Creating jqplot graph using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, jqplot

I'm not really good at English sorry.

I don't know how to pass values to jqplot application.

the php webpage shows
[{"PER":"23"},{"PER":"47"},{"PER":"86"},{"PER":"25"},{"PER":"74"}]
which came from mysql server.

the table has one column and values are 23, 47, 86, 25, 74

this is the php code.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","autoset");
mysql_select_db("test");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT PER FROM Evaluation");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output)); 

mysql_close();

?>
```

this is html sample file.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
        
        var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot) {
            var ret = null;
            $.ajax({
                // have to use synchronous here, else returns before data is fetched
                async: false,
                url: url,
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    ret = data;
                }
            });
            return ret;
        };
     
        var jsonurl ="http://127.0.0.1/index.php"; //"../report/jsondata.txt";

        plot1 = $.jqplot("chart2", jsonurl, {
            title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
            dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    
            animate: true,
            animateReplot: true,
            cursor: {
              show: true,
              zoom: true,
              looseZoom: true,
              showTooltip: false,
 
            },
            series:[   
              {
                label:'a',
                color: '#FF0000',
                rendererOptions: {
                  animation: {
                    speed: 2000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                  label:'b',
                  color: '#0000FF',
                  rendererOptions: {
                    animation: {
                      speed: 2000
                    }
                  }
                }
            ],
            
            
            axesDefaults: {
              pad: 0
            },
            axes: {
              xaxis: {
                label: "Period",
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,

              },
              yaxis: {
                label: "PER",
                tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%d"
                },
                rendererOptions: {
                  //forceTickAt0: true
                }
              },
              y2axis: {
                tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%d"
                },
                rendererOptions: {
                  alignTicks: true
                  //forceTickAt0: true
                }
              }
            },
            
            
            highlighter: {
              show: true,
              showLabel: true, 
              tooltipAxes: 'y',
              sizeAdjust: 7.5 , tooltipLocation : 'ne'
            },
            
            
            legend: {
              show: true,
              location: 'sw',
              placement: 'outside'
            }  
          });
    });
```

when I used

```
var jsonurl ="../report/jsondata.txt"; it worked.
```

jsondata.txt included [[ 23, 47, 86, 25, 74 ]].

but when I used the other one it doesn't. I want to get values from server.
I guess there are problems passing values.

please help specifically T.T

thanks!

**EDIT**

this is the table. the contents have only one table. I want to pass PER's values.

> **ENTERPRISE PERIOD EPS STOCKPRICE PER**
>
> 232          232   23    432      **23**
>
> 236           56   65    43       **47**
>
> 574           53   45    75       **86**
>
> 453           45   45    265      **25**
>
> 46            63   67    45       **74**

I just made values temporarily to test.

Comment: Show the contents of the file which doesn't work.

Comment: Your code accepts data in JSON format, so as I see you should have something like `[[232, 232, 23, 432, 23]]`. If you want to have two dimentional array, then `[[232, 232, 23, 432, 23], [236, 56, 65, 43, 47], [...]]`

Comment: I'm asking how to do what you are saying..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the format of your json data, which is coming from the (associative) $output array. you don't want those '"PER"'s in it! try replacing these lines of code:

```
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
```

with these:

```
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e["PER"];

print ('['.json_encode($output).']');
```

this will change $output from an associative array, to a standard array of integers.

and the print line adds additional square brackets around the json data - which the jqplot requires.